# vba loop through a list of names and perform function. On the second loop start where last loop finished

Tags: excel, vba

The code below works really well at the end of each loop I call a "shuffle module" which randomly shuffles the names in the list and the continues with the loop which randomises the order in which the people are allocated to each date, however because people are not always available I am finding that people are being allocated to successive dates which is not what is required.Rather than "shuffle" the list it would be better to allocate in turn.
The part I am struggling with is the question of how to loop through the list of names in turn and when the next date allocation occurs start from the next person in the list. so to try and explain a little more easily.

A list of names lets say 1-20 in column A
column B has a date
column C has a date
column D has a date

I need 3 people for date B, 2 people for Date C, and 5 people for Date D.
at the moment allocation starts at person 1 checks if they are available if they are then it allocates them to that date and moves to person 2 and so on.
lets assume that persons 1, 2 and 3 are all available on that date then persons 1, 2 and 3 will be allocated to that date.
When allocation for that column has finished the program moves to column B what needs to happen here is that the check for availability should start at person 4, but the code I have starts at person 1 again. This is not what I want, the check must start at the next person in the list not back at the start again. Is anyone able to advise how I can adjust this code to make it do what I require. hopefully some kind soul can help me out with this as I am totally stuck. thank you for your time in looking at this

```
Public Sub copyothers()
Dim listofcells As Range
Dim currentname As String
Dim foundrow As Integer
Dim foundcolumn As Integer
Dim counter As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim personcount() As Variant


Sheets("Availability").Activate

personcount = Sheets("Availability").Range("B3:AR3").Value 'check the number 
of people required in each column and record it for later

For i = 2 To 44
Sheets("Availability").Activate
Sheets("Availability").Range("a2").Select

counter = personcount(1, i - 1) - 1 'take the first number reduce it by 1 and move one column right right each time program loops
If Not Sheets("Availability").Cells(2, i) = "" Then
    Sheets("Availability").Range(Cells(2, i), Cells(2, i).End(xlDown)).Select
Else
    GoTo skip:  'If the column has no data then skip to next column
End If
Set listofcells = Selection

Sheets("allocation").Activate
Range("a2").Select


For Each singlecell In listofcells
        If counter > 0 Then
            If singlecell = "Available" Then
            foundcolumn = singlecell.Column 'record the column number where "Available" was found
            currentname = Sheets("Availability").Range("A" & singlecell.Row) 'record the name of the person in the row where "Available" was found
            Set foundName = Sheets("Allocation").Range("A:A").Find(What:=currentname, LookIn:=xlValues) 'find the persons name in "Allocation" sheet
            foundrow = foundName.Row
                If Sheets("allocation").Cells(foundrow, foundcolumn) = "" Then
                Sheets("allocation").Cells(foundrow, foundcolumn) = "X" 'place X in the same cell as it appeared in "Availability" sheet
                counter = counter - 1
                End If
            End If
        End If

Next singlecell

skip:
Call Shuffle
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately I can't just comment because of low reputation, however I have a few questions. In your if not/then statement, why do you call "Skip"? To go to the next column, simply letting the else portion blank would likely be more effective. Also, what is the purpose of the "Shuffle" in the "Skip:" portion of the code?

Also, one thing you could try is instead of

```
For singlecells in listofcells
*Code
Next Singlecell
```

Try

```
For singlecells + marker in listofcells
*Code
mixer = mixer + 1
Next Singlecell
```

The "marker" should stop your program from reiterating over each person again.

Comment: sorry I am confused by your code do you mean;For singlecells + marker in listofcells
*Code
mixer = mixer + 1
Next Singlecell if so I don't quite understand how that will work however I will give it a try and let you know how I get on

Comment: No sorry, I mean more so that each time you run through your loop, use the "Marker" variable to count how many iterations that you have gone through. That way, if you a list of 100 names, if your code runs through to  #40, and then runs, when it "resets" as you had mentioned as an issue above, the "Counter" variable will be equal to 40, and your code loop will start off with number 40 instead of number 1 (hopefully).

Comment: I have tried this and it does not compile where does mixer come from did you mean marker?